# Symfony2 authentication: How can I select a user provider dynamically?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

On the login form, the user will be allowed to select the company he belongs to.
Depending on what he selects, he'll be authenticated against database1 or database2 or LDAPserver1, etc.

I know there's a chain provider option in Symfony2 but I don't want the application to loop over all the providers and instead go directly to the appropriate server.

Basically, I want to select the user provider dynamically.

How can I do that in Symfony2?

Or what might be a better solution for this kind of authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you looking for?

[dynamic form modification](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2014/03/19/dynamic-form-modification-in-symfony2/)

Comment: The form will be static. It'll have a dropdown field which will display the list of companies, and two input fields for the username and the password. What I want to know is if there's a possibility to change the user provider based on what company the user selected so that he'll be authenticated on a LDAP server or on the local database, etc.
But thanks for your answer.